# How to store selected data in a list in vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have filtered data in a myRawData table where the resulting query will be inserted in myImportedData table.

The situation is that I am going to have some formatting in the filtered data before I will insert it into myImportedData.

My question is how to store the filtered data in a list? Because that is the easiest way for me to reiterate over the filtered data.

So far here is my code, It only store 1 data in the list.

```
    Public Sub ImportData()

    Dim con2 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=server;Database=dataRecord;User ID=root;")

    con2.Open()
    Dim sql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT dataRec FROM myRawData WHERE dataRec LIKE '%20130517%' ", con2)

    Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim dataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter()
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = sql
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "dataRec")
    Dim datTable As DataTable = dataSet.Tables("dataRec")

    listOfCanteenSwipe.Add(Convert.ToString(sql.ExecuteScalar()))

    'ListBox1.Items.Add(listOfCanteenSwipe(0))

    End Sub
```

Example of data in the myRawData table is this:

```
    myRawData Table
     --------------------------
    ' id    '    dataRec
     --------------------------
    '  1    '    K10201305170434010040074A466
    '  2    '    K07201305170434010040074UN45
```

Please help. Thank you.

EDIT:

What i just want to achieve is to store my filtered data in a list. I used list to loop over the filtered data - and I have no problem with that.

After storing in a list, i will now segragate the information in the dataRec field to be imported in the myImportedData table.

To add some knowledge, i will format the dataRec field just like below:

```
K07        ----> Loc
20130514   ----> date
0455       ----> time
010        ----> temp
18006D9566 ----> id
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in your description, I think i speak for everyone when I say we have very little clue what you are trying to achieve.

What are you trying to achieve?
the data in SQL server, you are trying to pull into a .NET datatable to do what with ?
what further operations do you want to perform on the datatable?
do you need to update the source data in SQL server in the end ?
please elaborate a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
dim x as integer

for x = 0 to datTable.rows.count - 1
  listOfCanteenSwipe.Add(datTable.rows(x).item("datarec"))
next
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your SQL statement to split the field out for you ?

You shuold use the power of SQL to perform any data manipulation you can perform at the server, It is far quicker, has less overhead on the server and was designed for this very purpose

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(dataRec,1,3) as [Loc]
,SUBSTRING(dataRec,4,8) as [date]
,SUBSTRING(dataRec,12,4) as [time]
,SUBSTRING(dataRec,16,3) as [temp]
,SUBSTRING(dataRec,19,10) as [Loc]
FROM myRawData WHERE dataRec LIKE '%20130517%'
```

then load this directly into your .NET datatable "myImportedData"

Comment: These shoud be posted as comments, not as an answer

Comment: Ok @Steve updated to an answer can you release the negative score pretty please

Comment: If you want @Steve to get notified that you are responding to him, you need to put an @ symbol in front of his name.

Comment: Thanks @StevenDoggart for helping me get to grips with the very twitteresk style commenting hopefully Steve will see it now...

Comment: @AndrePageot, I have not downvoted you for this. I have just flagged your answer as not an answer to signal a moderator to move your answer to the comments section (if they still feel that this is correct)

Comment: I see that you have already moved the original text to the comments section. Well, I am sorry but I can't see who downvoted you. But don't worry, you get downvotes sometimes, just post an useful answer and you are beyond this

Comment: It's hard, but try to not get bent out of shape by down-votes.  Even the best of us on here still get down-votes occasionally.  Try to learn from them when they are valid, and try to ignore it when they are not :)

Comment: i already done that processing in my SQL. I didnt just put it in my the code because it will be very long..

Answer (score 0):

After getting the data in Data Table you can convert it to a generic list. Then you can use this list for further operations:

```
List<MyType> list = dataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
    .Select(dr => dr.Field<MyType>(columnName)).ToList();
```